# How do I rendering views based on multiple queries in Express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I have a collection with various `data` that I would **like** to use when rendering my `ejs` page. I only seem to be able to render contents from **ONE** query and not other queries.

Kindly help me figure out how to render the contents from other queries.

Find below some of the contents of my collection:
[image: contents within my collection]

Find below my rendered `ejs` page
[image: the rendered ejs page]

Pay special attention to the **Unidentified** in the *Transactions from: **Unidentified** county* sentence.

Now... lets take a look at the code that generates this page:

```
function county (req, res) {
transModel.findOne({ transCounty : /Nairobi/i,
                        })
                        .limit(5)
                        .select({ transCounty:1})
                        .exec( (err, result)=> {
                            if (err) throw err;
                                console.log('>> ' +result); 
                                console.log('We in county function!');
                                return result;
                            });    
};

app.get('/list', async (req,res)=> {

console.log('## ' +county());
transModel.find({transIndustry: 'Pharmacy'}, (err, docs)=> {
if (!err) 
    {
        res.render('list',  {data : docs, countyName: county}); 
    }
else
    {
//          res.status(status).send(body);      
    }
        
})
});
```

In the console, the code above logs:

```
## undefined
>> { _id: 609f7ed8fe1fd8b3193b0b77, transCounty: 'Nairobi' }
We in county function!
```

And now find below the `ejs` file contents:

```
<body>
    <h1> 
        Transactions
    </h1>

    <p> Transactions from: <b> <%= countyName.transCounty %> </b> County: </p>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th> _id  </th>
            <th> Transaction Amount </th>       
            <th> Transaction Industry </th> 
        </tr>
        <% data.forEach(function(entry) {%>
        <tr>
            <td> <%=entry._id%> </td> 
            <td> <%=entry.transAmount%> </td>               
            <td> <%=entry.transIndustry%> </td>     
        </tr>
        <%});%>
        
    </table>
```

Kindly help me understand where I am going wrong and how I can get the `<%= countyName.transCounty %>` to display **Nairobi** in my rendered `ejs` file

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between `docs` and `county` is that `docs` is the results from a database-query (ok!), while `county` is a function which you only reference to and never run *(problem 1)*, but if you were to run it still returns nothing *(problem 2)*, but it does run a query, so you have that going for you!

so, not the complete solution, but just to point you in the right direction:

- You need to call county at some point using `county()` with parenthesises.
- Since the nature of database queries is that they are asynchronous you need to either use a **callback pattern** or a **promise-based solution**.

#### A callback solution could look like:

```
   // Here we are calling the function, and the entire function-argument is the callback.
   county((countyResult /* the callback will be called with result in the future */) => {
        // wrap your existing code, 
        // because the result will only be available inside the callback
        transModel.find({transIndustry: 'Pharmacy'}, (err, docs) => {
            ...
            res.render('list', {data : docs, countyName: countyResult});
        });
   });
```

And the called function could look something like this:

```
function county (callback /* accept a callback */) {
    transModel.findOne({ transCounty : /Nairobi/i })
        .limit(5)
        .select({ transCounty:1})
        .exec((err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            callback(result);  // Use the callback when you have the result.
        });    
}
```

Because the need to wrap callbacks the result never becomes very pretty.

#### *Instead* you could use promises. for example:

```
let countyResult = await county();
let docs = await transModel.find({transIndustry: 'Pharmacy'}).exec();
res.render('list', {data : docs, countyName: countyResult});
```

And the called function could look something like this:

```
function county (req, res) {
    return transModel
        .findOne({ transCounty : /Nairobi/i })
        .limit(5)
        .select({ transCounty: 1})
        .exec();  // If you use exec without a callback it'll return a promise.
};
```

This is much cleaner but error handling needs to be done using try/catch.
For example:

```
let countyResult;
try {
     countyResult = await county();
catch(err) {
    throw err; 
    // Of course, if all you do is throw, then you don't even need the `try/catch`.
    // Try/catch is to catch thrown errors and handle them.
}
```

You still might want to check that the result contains anything. A query with no data found is not an error.

*Disclaimer: The code is for describing the flow. I've tried to get it right, but nothing here is tested, so there is bound to be errors.*